# Combina pyramid with jinja2 install_gettext_translations function?

Tags: translation, jinja2, pyramid

I have a pyramid application that uses a translation factory defined in this way:

```
from pyramid.i18n import get_localizer, TranslationStringFactory
from pyramid.threadlocal import get_current_request


def add_renderer_globals(event):
    request = event.get('request')
    if request is None:
        request = get_current_request()
    event['_'] = request.translate
    event['localizer'] = request.localizer

tsf = TranslationStringFactory('climmob3')

def add_localizer(event):
    request = event.request
    localizer = get_localizer(request)

    def auto_translate(string):
        return localizer.translate(tsf(string))
    request.localizer = localizer
    request.translate = auto_translate
```

It works fine, however somewhere else I use jinja2 render() function to render small pieces of reusable code (snippets) as a jinja2 extension:

```
from jinja2 import Environment
jinjaEnv = Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.i18n'])

output = template.render(snippetVars=kw,renderer='snippet')
```

The problem here is that when I use the '_' translation function in the template code I get:

> UndefinedError: 'gettext' is undefined

I saw some posts that maybe I need to use jinjaEnv.install_gettext_translations() but I cannot make it work. I tried:

```
jinjaEnv.install_gettext_translations(pyramid.il8n)
jinjaEnv.install_gettext_translations(tsf)
```

How can I integrate jinjaEnv.install_gettext_translations() with my pyramid translation factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your exact case, you could use pyramid_jinja2 or get inspiration from it. It creates a GetTextWrapper https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_jinja2/blob/28944ce627745691ccd1603c56251e038aadd892/pyramid_jinja2/i18n.py that makes its way in the options passed when creating the Environment https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_jinja2/blob/28944ce627745691ccd1603c56251e038aadd892/pyramid_jinja2/settings.py#L133
https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_jinja2/blob/28944ce627745691ccd1603c56251e038aadd892/pyramid_jinja2/__init__.py#L394
https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_jinja2/blob/28944ce627745691ccd1603c56251e038aadd892/pyramid_jinja2/__init__.py#L404-L405

The wrapper is needed because the localizer will change every request, depending on the user locale.

Or you can pass the gettext and ngettext arguments directly when you render. In you case, it would look something like:

```
localizer = request.localizer

def gt(message):
    return localizer.translate(message, domain='your-domain')

def ngt(singular, plural, n):
    return localizer.pluralize(singular, plural, n, domain='your-domain')

output = template.render(
    snippetVars=kw,
    renderer='snippet',
    gettext=gt,
    ngettext=ngt,
    )
```